# Are resources in the same origin if they have different IP's but the same domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, cross-domain

I have a backend server hosted in the cloud (AWS) and a front-end which is just a Docker container running NGINX routed to an index.html. The backend is a cluster of containers behind a Load Balancer (ALB), so from my understanding this would be considered one "domain" because I access the backend through the ALB's DNS address. The frontend runs on a separate EC2 instance from the cluster. In this situation, the backend is on a different domain from the frontend, which means I would need to enable CORS to allow resources to be shared from the backend to the frontend. Once I get the domain setup, would it be possible to have the two ends be on the same domain so that CORS is no longer needed? Will they be considered to be under the same domain even though they are on two different IP's?

Comment: As far as CORS is concerned, the origin is the host portion of the URL.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The precise definition is in [section 4 of RFC 6454](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-4), which in most common cases comes down to the origin of a resource having three components:

1. Scheme part of the URL, e.g. `https`
2. Host part of the URL, e.g. `example.com`
3. Port number, e.g. 443

The IP address used to access the host does not enter into consideration here, so in the scenario you describe the frontend and the backend would have the same origin.